# What key command is this keyboard sending

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

[image: https://imgur.com/DXG8lyz]

This iPad keyboard has a keyboard button that unhides the on-screen keyboard when the keyboard is connected.

What command is this sending?

I've tried a keylogger on my laptop, but no joy.

Thanks.

Comment: On my Apple Wireless keyboard the Disc Eject button does the same thing if that helps any.

Comment: That's good to know, I'll try to replicate that. Thanks